# Вылезает ошибка Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.ConsoleKeyInfo" к типу "System.IConvertible". Не понимаю как решить эту проблему

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество чисел");
int kolvo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
for (int i = 0; i < kolvo; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Введите число: ");
    float x = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadKey());
    string kop = null;
    string res1 = kop ?? "0";
    float kop2 = Convert.ToSingle(kop);
    kop2 = kop2 + x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите получить прочтённый символ - используйте свойство `KeyChar`, однако, как я понимаю вы хотите прочитать число - тогда не используйте `Console.ReadKey()`, есть отличная функция - `Console.ReadLine()`:

```
int kolvo = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```